# How do I put the values between brackets spanning multiple lines into a list in python?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm fairly new to python and regex but I'm trying to figure out a way to do this.

I have a file that looks like this:

```
random text up here

group groupfoo {

    item_1
    item_2
    item_3
}

group groupbar {
    item_1
    item_2
    item_3
}

random text down here
```

There are several groups like this in this file.  The group names (groupfoo, groupbar, etc) are all unique.  I'd like to be able to somehow create tuples based on the group names and have the items as values.

Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way without regex.  Though you might want to use regex for the line with the `replace` calls below.  But if your format is as strict as you show it to be in your question, then this will work.  Simple (very simple) state machine.

```
import collections

grouper = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open("groups.txt") as groups:
    in_group = False
    for line in groups:
        if '{' in line:
            in_group = True
            group_name = line.replace('group ', '').replace(' {', '').strip()
            continue
        if '}' in line:
            in_group = False
        if in_group:
            grouper[group_name].append(line.strip())
print grouper
```

**OUTPUT**

```
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'groupbar': ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3'], 'groupfoo': ['item_1', 'item_2', 'item_3']})
```